# An integral involving $1/\zeta(s)$ and the zeros of $\zeta(s)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

In my thesis, i stumbled across the following problem:

Define $$F(\sigma, T)=\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T}^{T} \frac{1}{|\zeta(\sigma+it)|^2} \mathrm{d}T$$ where $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function.

Is the statement that $\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} F(\sigma, T)=O(1)$  equivalent to the statement that $\zeta(s)\neq 0$ for $\Re(s)\geq\sigma$ ?

Comment: Might it be possible that, for example, there are zeros of $\zeta$ with real part $\frac34$, yet $F(\frac23,T)$ is bounded?

Comment: @GregMartin, i think that's exactly what my question is...

Comment: Let me rephrase then: what reason do you have to think that $F(\frac23,T)$ should know about zeros with real part $\frac34$?

Comment: @GregMartin, indeed $F(\sigma, T)$ seems to have nothing to do with zeos with real part $>\sigma$. But what of those with real part *equal* to $\sigma$ ?